# Optimizing a summation with restraints and boundaries

Tags: optimization, summation

I have a summation of the following form that I want to find the maximum and minimum values for:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{N}{\frac{(f_i-g_i)^2}{f_i+g_i}}$$

Given the constraints $\sum_{i=1}^{N}f_i=1$, $\sum_{i=1}^{N}g_i=1$. And given the boundaries of f and g: $f_i>0$ and $g_i>0$ for all $i$. I wanted to try running code and taking derivatives with respect to $f_i$ and $g_i$ to do a gradient descent optimization, but I was wondering if there was a closed form method to determine this Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: Clearly the minimum is 0, achieved when $ f_i = g_i$.

Comment: Yes I can see that, thanks @CalvinLin! Is the maximum that obvious?

Comment: The minimum (not maximum) is obvious yes. You have a sum of squares with positive coefficients.

Comment: @CalvinLin how could I go about then determining the maximum? It seems to be 1 from when I tried some examples, but not sure how to rigorously prove it

Comment: For $N=1$, the maximum is obviously $0$.  For $N>1$, the maximum (supremum) appears to be $2$.  Take $f_1=g_2=1-\epsilon$ and $f_i=g_i=\epsilon/(N-1)$ for all other $i$.